# making a hole in a glass tube having water

Tags: surface-tension, fluid-statics

A glass tube that has been put inside water such that water rises up some height. It is upright and open at the end which is inside water, closed at above. Would making a hole in the tube at some height below the water level make the water pour out of the tube or does it stay there making a protrusion?

Comment: As I commented on your previous question, if both ends are open, the level of the water in the tube, will be the same as that of the water level in the basin. If the tube is closed, any hole below the water level will not change the water level in the tube. A hole above the water level will effectively make the tube open at both ends again.

Comment: Related : [Effects of making a hole in a Mercury barometer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516782/238167)

Answer (score -1):

Water does not pour out. As the water stars protruding out, the force of surface tension pulls it towards the liquid-air interface that is backwards.Let the radius of the hole made in the tube is r, then the maximum amount of excess pressure that the water can withstand such that it does not fall out of the tube is numerically equal to (2*s)/(r) where s is surface tension of water-glass interface. Let the radius of the tube is R.

Hence the pressure at the bottom of the water is equal to atmospheric pressure + (2*s)/(R).

As we move up the water column, pressure decreases. Hence at any point above the lowest, the pressure difference cannot be more than (2*s)/(r) {as r < R} hence at no point, water can spill out of the tube.(even if orifice is as big as the radius of tube)